# Nginx reverse proxy didnt load site correctly

Tags: variables, nginx, static, proxypass, server-name

I have an `nginx` configuration which listens to any subdomain `*.mydomain.com`,
and I want to use subdomain as variable, to proxy request to other site.
Here is my nginx configuration

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name "~^(?<subdomain>.*).mydomain.com";

    location / {
            resolver 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 ipv6=off;
            proxy_pass http://hosting.mydomain.com/$subdomain/;
            proxy_redirect off;
            access_log /var/log/nginx/proxy.log;
    }
```

}

As I request the site directly and it loads perfectly

[Site placed on AWS S3, and bucket static website address cnamed to mydomain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK9sH.png)

However, when I try to access via `user1.mydomain.com, the page didn't load images, and css`

[This is the same site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQtI8.png)

And in browser network panel shows

[Difference between direct and proxy access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4onF.png)

This issue is made, because I have many sites stored in S3 bucket and located in different folders (the folder name is used as subdomain).
And I want to use a single domain to access all of them via subdomains.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to proxy pass the URI, you're serving `user1/index.html` for every request, including for JS and CSS requests, it's why all of responses are the same size (2kb, the size of `user1/index.html`), and it's also why you're getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` in the first line of `Enterprise_skeleton.bundle.js` because it's returning an HTML document that starts with `<!doctype html>` instead of the actual JS bundle.

Change

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://hosting.mydomain.com/$subdomain/;
}
```

to

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://hosting.mydomain.com/$subdomain$uri;
}
```